# What do we call the maximum power of prime factorization?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, terminology

Any positive integer n > 1 can be written uniquely in the following prime factorization form :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtbRz.png

where p1 < p2 < ... < pk are primes and the ni are positive integers.This is Fundamental theorem of arithmetic.
what do we call every prime power pi^ni.I want to know the concept .

Comment: $n_i$ is the $p_i$-adic [valuation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order) of $n$

Comment: The problem with knowing what to call it is you'll will find yourself talking to someone who isn't familiar with the term.  All I can say is that "highest power of $p$ that divides $n$" is tedious but is understood.... There's probably a term but I dont know it... (And then I read J.W. Tanner's comment... which is a case in point.  If you talk of the $p$-adic valuation that's very exact and clear but your students won't know what you mean at first.)

Comment: $\ p^{\large k}\! \parallel n\,$ means $k$ is the highest power of $p$ that divides $n.\ \ $

Comment: thanks.I hope the term is expressed by at most two words ,as we use primorial to denote  the product of the first n primes。